# getting "NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken okta.config.angular!" while upgrading to angular8 to angular10

Tags: angular, angular8, angular10, kentor-authservices

NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[OktaAuthGuard -> OktaAuthService -> InjectionToken okta.config.angular -> InjectionToken okta.config.angular -> InjectionToken okta.config.angular]:

[image]

it's working fine in angular6 and 8 but while upgrading to angular 10 getting these error...

What to do can any one help me out...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm importing both the OktaAuthModule and the OktaAuthGuard providers, but I'm struggling to get it to load. It looks like the error is from this line of code within the library itself, so we must be missing some required prerequisite somehow:
    var OKTA_CONFIG = new i0.InjectionToken('okta.config.angular');
    var OKTA_AUTH = new i0.InjectionToken('okta.auth');

Answer (score 0):

You need to import okaauthguard in app.module.ts
That's what this error says